# Extjs 6 Define a chained store using Ext.define

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs6, extjs6-classic

Can a chained store be define using Ext.define statement? I tried the following code but I'm getting errors:

```
Ext.define('MyProject.store.RelFiltered', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.ChainedStore',
    source:'MyProject.store.Rel',
    alias: 'store.releasesFiltered'
});
```

The errors I receive are:

```
Ext.data.ChainedStore.applySource(): Invalid source "MyProject.store.Rel" specified for Ext.data.ChainedStore
```

and

```
Ext.mixin.Bindable.applyBind(): Cannot use bind config without a viewModel
```

I got the idee from [this](http://www.extjs-tutorial.com/extjs5/chained-store) post, but it seems that the code is incomplete.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can a chained store be define using Ext.define statement?

Definitely yes. But the [source config](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.data.ChainedStore.html#cfg-source) of the [chained store](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.data.ChainedStore.html) says that it should be either a store instance or the id of an existing store.

So the code would look like this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.MyChainedStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.ChainedStore',

    storeId: 'MyChainedStore',
    //source using storeID
    source: 'OriginalStore'

});

Ext.define('MyApp.store.OriginalStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    requires: [
        'Ext.data.field.Field'
    ],

    storeId: 'OriginalStore',
    data: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'commodi'
    }],
    fields: [{
        name: 'id'
    }, {
        name: 'name'
    }]
});
```

Check out this fiddle example https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1kk4